# Как обрезать все строки столбца датасета?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть задача: Сетнимент анализ по plot файла wiki_movie_plots_deduped.csv на английском bert

Пример датасета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Планировал добавить столбец Sentiment, который определяет предобученная модель:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import transformers
from transformers import pipeline

movie_df = pd.read_csv("wiki_movie_plots_deduped.csv", sep=',')

movies = movie_df

SentimentClassifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")

def FunctionBERTSentiment(inpText):
  return(SentimentClassifier(inpText)[0]['label'])

movies['Sentiment']=movies['Plot'].apply(FunctionBERTSentiment)
```

Но питон ругается на размер строки:

*The size of tensor a (760) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1*

Есть ли способ предварительно обработать столбец, обрезав все строки до максимального размера в 512 символов?

Comment: вы привели в вопросе все что угодно кроме того, что нужно. пример датасета приведите хотя бы.

Answer (score 1):

Обрезать строки в столбце фрейма можно с помощью [`pandas.Series.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) или, в сокращенной записи, `str[]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['a'*550,'b'*511,'c'*100]})
df['length'] = df.text.str.len()
print(df)
df.text = df.text.str.slice(0,512) # или df.text = df.text.str[:512]
df['length'] = df.text.str.len()
print(df)
```

```
                                                text  length
0  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...     550
1  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb...     511
2  cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc...     100
                                                text  length
0  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...     512
1  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb...     511
2  cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc...     100
```